# Allocating matrix / structure data instead of string name to variable

Tags: string, matlab, structure

I have a script that opens a folder and does some processing on the data present. Say, there's a file "XYZ.tif".

Inside this tif file, there are two groups of datasets, which show up in the workspace as

```
data.ch1eXYZ
```

and

```
data.ch3eXYZ
```

If I want to continue with the 2nd set, I can use
A=data.ch3eXYZ

However, XYZ usually is much longer and varies per file, whereas data.ch3e is consistent.

Therefore I tried
A=strcat('data.ch3e','origfilename');
where origfilename of course is XYZ, which has (automatically) been extracted before.

However, that gives me a string A (since I practically typed

```
A='data.ch3eXYZ'
```

instead of the matrix that data.ch3eXYZ actually is.
I think it's just a problem with ()'s, []'s, or {}'s but Ican't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems hard to avoid `eval` in this case. Try `eval(['A = ' strcat('data.ch3e','origfilename') ';'])`

Comment: Ah, the infamous eval. It works perfectly btw! Thanks for including the ';' too, probably would not have figured out where exactly to put it in. Eval keeps confusing me, maybe I'll remember this time.

Comment: As a general rule, if you need `eval` you probably should be doing things differently so that you don't need it. In this case, maybe use cells instead of fields. Oh, I see now that @excaza's answer solves it with dynamic field names. Clever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the string, [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) should help you here and are far better than `eval`

Slightly modified example from the linked blog post:

```
fldnm = 'fred';
s.fred = 18;
y = s.(fldnm)
```

Returns:

```
y =

    18
```

So for your case:

```
test = data.(['ch3e' origfilename]);
```

Should be sufficient

Edit: Link to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)

Comment: See, I didn't need a solution to my problem, just the correct way of what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot, works like a charm! :)

Comment: @user3783502 It really should be better documented, I used MATLAB for more than 6 years before I discovered the syntax. It's extremely powerful on its own, even more so when compared to `eval`, which is generally used in its place.